# Limit points of the following set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

What are the limiting points of the following set $$\boldsymbol{\Pi} =\left\{\boldsymbol{\pi}=\left[\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3\right]^\intercal \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^3:\sum_{i=1}^3 \pi_i =1 \right\}?$$
Is the set of limit points of $\boldsymbol{\Pi}$ $$L(\boldsymbol{\Pi}) = \left\{\boldsymbol{\pi}=\left[\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3\right]^\intercal \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^3:\sum_{i=1}^3 \pi_i =1 \right\}?$$

*The following is my thinking:*

If we take its limit from the direction of $\pi_3,$ consider
$$\boldsymbol{\Pi}_{n} = \left\{\boldsymbol{\pi}=\left[\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3\right]^\intercal \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^3:\pi_3 = \frac{1}{n}, \sum_{i=1}^3 \pi_i =1 \right\},$$ where $n>1.$ Then, the set of limit points of $\boldsymbol{\Pi}_{n}$ is $$L(\boldsymbol{\Pi}_{n}) = \left\{\boldsymbol{\pi}=\left[\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3\right]^\intercal \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^3:\pi_1,\pi_2>0,\pi_3\geq 0,\sum_{i=1}^3 \pi_i =1 \right\}$$ and similar procedure can be applied from the direction of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$.

*Here, $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ implies that the vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ is nonnegative in all of its coordinates and $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++}$ implies that the vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ is strictly positive in all its coordinates.*

Comment: Why did you delete your answer @KaviRamaMurthy?

Comment: Why the transpose of a matrix? A 3-tuple is just $(\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3)$ right ? what's your definition of limiting point?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ is a three-dimensional vector. I was looking at the definition: If $A$ is a subset of topological space $X$ and if $x \in X$ then $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ in some point other than $x$ itself. Now I look at the definition again, I updated my thinking a little bit.

Comment: It's just a point of $\Bbb R^3$. So I'd rather use 3-tuples. It's topology. not linear analysis.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of  limit points $\{[\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3]^{T}: \pi_i \geq 0, \sum \pi_i=1\}$.

It is clear that limit points have to lie in this set. Let $[\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3]^{T}$ be any point in this set. There exists $i$ such that $\pi_i >0$. Take $j \neq i$. Now consider the sequence $[\pi_{1n}',\pi_{2n}',\pi_{3n}']^{T}$ where $\pi_{in}'=\pi_i-\frac 1 n, \pi_{jn}'=\pi_j+\frac 1 n$ and $\pi_{kn}'=\pi_k$ for $k \notin \{i,j\}$. This sequence converges to $[\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3]^{T}$

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot!

Comment: Just one question regarding the notation, having subscripts $i$, $j$, and $k$ here seems not necessary. Can we just say that: consider the sequence $[\pi_{1n}',\pi_{2n}',\pi_{3n}']^{T},$ where $n >1,$ and $\pi_{1n}' = \pi_1-1/n, \pi_{2n}' = \pi_2+1/n$ and $\pi_{3n}'=\pi_3$?

Comment: @Xuan If $\pi_1=0$ then your $\pi'_{1n}<0$. Remember that my $\pi_i$'s are just non-negative and some of them could be $0$.